# Saving arrays of elements in the json object into different rows

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

While saving json object containing multiple jsons, the json object is being saved as a single array instead of multiple rows.

sample json:

```
[
    {
     "id"   : 1, -- this is not a primary key and not unique but cannot be null
     "name" : "John Doe",
     "phone" : [
       { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"},
       { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
     ]
   },
   {
    "id"   : 2, -- this is not a primary key and not unique but cannot be null
    "name" : "Jane Doe",
    "phone" : [
      { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"},
      { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what i need after saving in the database

```
id   name         phone    
1    John Doe     { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"}
1    John Doe     { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
2    Jane Doe     { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"}
2    Jane Doe     { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
```

This is what I am getting

```
id   name         phone    
1    John Doe     [{ "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"},{ "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}]
2    Jane Doe    [{ "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"},{ "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}]
```

here is how i am parsing the json object to pojo and saving to db

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class person{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    @Transient 
    JsonNode phoneJson;

    private static OhjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    getter/setter

    @Transient
    public JsonNode getPhoneJson(){
        return phoneJson;
    }

    public void setPhoneJson(JsonNode phoneJson){
        this.phoneJson = phoneJson;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="phone")
    public String getPhone() throws Exception{
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(phoneJson);
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) throws Exception{
        this.phone = mapper.readTree(phone);
    }
}
```

dao- save

```
personRepository.save(person)
```

any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Multiple jSON Column

```
[
    {
     "id"   : 1, -- this primary key and not unique but cannot be null
     "name" : { --this element can be empty/null
        "first" : "John",
        "last" : "Doe" 
      },
     "phone" : [
       { "type" : "home", "ref" : 1111111234},
       { "type" : "work", "ref" : 2222222222}
     ]
   },
   {
    "id"   : 2, -- this primary key and not unique but cannot be null
    "name" : {
        "first" : "Jane",
        "last" : "Doe" 
      },
    "phone" : [
      { "type" : "home", "ref" : 1111111234},
      { "type" : "work", "ref" : 2222222222}
    ]
  }
]
```

how do i get result as below

```
id   name                   phone    
1    [{John},{Doe}]     { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"}
1    [{John},{Doe}]     { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
2    [{Jane},{Doe}]     { "type" : "home", "ref" : "111-111-1234"}
2    [{Jane},{Doe}]     { "type" : "work", "ref" : "222-222-2222"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to duplicate `Person` objects `n` times where `n` is size of `phone` array. To make it clear, I propose, to create two separate models which we can use separately for parsing `JSON` and saving in `DB`. Below you can find simple example which:

1. Parses `JSON` to `List<JsonPerson>`
2. Converts `List<JsonPerson>` to `List<Person>`
3. Prints `List<Person>` (you can save it to `DB`)

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        CollectionType personsType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, JsonPerson.class);

        // parse
        List<JsonPerson> jsonPersons = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, personsType);

        // convert
        List<Person> persons = jsonPersons.stream()
                .map(p -> p.mapTo(mapper))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        persons.forEach(System.out::println);

        // save persons to DB
        // ...
    }
}

class JsonPerson {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayNode phone;

    public List<Person> mapTo(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        phone.elements().forEachRemaining(phone -> {
            persons.add(map(mapper, phone));
        });

        return persons;
    }

    private Person map(ObjectMapper mapper, JsonNode p) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(id);
        person.setName(name);
        try {
            person.setPhone(mapper.writeValueAsString(p));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return person;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Person {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Person{id=1, name='John Doe', phone='{"type":"home","ref":"111-111-1234"}'}
Person{id=1, name='John Doe', phone='{"type":"work","ref":"222-222-2222"}'}
Person{id=2, name='Jane Doe', phone='{"type":"home","ref":"111-111-1234"}'}
Person{id=2, name='Jane Doe', phone='{"type":"work","ref":"222-222-2222"}'}
```

Above code separates parsing `JSON` from other parts. Also, do not create `ObjectMapper` in each `POJO`. `POJO` should not know anything about `ObjectMapper` and `Jackson`.

### Update

Because `name` is `JSON Object` you can create new `POJO` - `Name` with `first` and `last` properties or treat it similarly to `phone` and deserialise to `JsonNode`:

```
class JsonPerson {

    private Integer id;
    private JsonNode name;
    private ArrayNode phone;

    public List<Person> mapTo(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        phone.elements().forEachRemaining(phone -> {
            persons.add(map(mapper, phone));
        });

        return persons;
    }

    private Person map(ObjectMapper mapper, JsonNode p) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(id);
        person.setName(getNameAsString());
        try {
            person.setPhone(mapper.writeValueAsString(p));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return person;
    }

    private String getNameAsString() {
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (name.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode nameObject = (ObjectNode) name;
            builder.append("[");
            builder.append("{").append(nameObject.get("first")).append("}");
            builder.append(",");
            builder.append("{").append(nameObject.get("last")).append("}");
            builder.append("]");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

After change above code should print:

```
Person{id=1, name='[{"John"},{"Doe"}]', phone='{"type":"home","ref":1111111234}'}
Person{id=1, name='[{"John"},{"Doe"}]', phone='{"type":"work","ref":2222222222}'}
Person{id=2, name='[{"Jane"},{"Doe"}]', phone='{"type":"home","ref":1111111234}'}
Person{id=2, name='[{"Jane"},{"Doe"}]', phone='{"type":"work","ref":2222222222}'}
```

`getNameAsString` method is simplified, you need to handle all corner cases and create `String` representation better for `null`, `empty` and `semi-empty` nodes.

Comment: Thank you Michal, I have updated my question as I am having multiple json columns but only phone column needs to be saved in different rows.
Also, while reading the value 
{List<JsonPerson> jsonPersons = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, personsType);}
How do i capture the incoming json request values? I used mapper.readtree in the modal class to convert it before saving to the database.

Comment: @404or505, in case other properties are complex objects you can always deserialise them to `POJO` classes or `*Node` class. Take a look on my answer after update.